# Create Flask Routes From List

Tags: flask, python-3.7

Is there a way to create flask routes from a list, so it will enter the variables you want depending what is in the list.

```
for x in movie_name:

 @app.route('/x')
 def x():

        films = os.listdir('static/'+x)

        b= 'static/'+x+'/'

        return flask.render_template(x+'.html', films=films, variable=variable, b=b)
```

where movie_name will be a list of names like Terminator, Cinderella etc, so the routes will be created for what is needed.

Is there any way for the route to go through the entire list and create pages depending on the names inside the list.

The files and list is being provided by another code that asks for the users input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ca be done with only one route. All you need to do is to get a dynamic route. An example is shown here :

> Step 1 : You have a page showing list of Movies
>
> Step 2 : You click on one movie(Having some movieName, and with a link to route to movie_name)
>
> Step 3 :

```
@app.route('/movie_name/<movieName>')
def movie_name(movieName):
    films = os.listdir('static/'+movieName)
    b= 'static/'+movieName+'/'
    return flask.render_template(movieName+'.html', films=films, variable=variable, b=b)
```